# Problem with duplicated classes - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I've created the project from template then I check some tutorial based on creating 1st activity and add some components with some png files as a references to those src/backgrounds. Application was working correctly at the beginning, but after adding some files in resources and injecting some dependencies into gradle. I've got problem with building. Related with duplicate class found error:

```
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-v4-22.2.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-v4-22.2.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-v4-22.2.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0)
```

I've tried to do some things, which is:

- add `android.enableJetfier=true`
- increase memory in org.gradle.jvmargs to more than 4Gb
- Refactor with unused resources
- Migrate to androidX (This one didn't do anything)

If this problem is related with no knowledge backgrounds (I believe it is). I would be thankful for providing some docs or any resources worth check, before going on. But I rather prefer to build app and learn in this process.

Repo:
https://github.com/KajtiChr/MobileAppAS

Comment: Remove this dependency from your gradle file: `com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0`, you should be using only the androidx stuff.

Comment: com.android.support is heavily outdated (about 4 to 5 years). Better try to find a tutorial that is newer.

Comment: Looking at my gradle files I do not see that I'm using:
core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0)

Answer (score 1):

You are not using old support-v4 libraries but your dependencies does. I solved this by removing this dependencies from your app `build.gradle.kts`. These two libraries are really old (last update 6 years ago) and they are not compatible. You should find something else for buttons and edittext, maybe just stick with material design.

```
implementation("info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5")
implementation("com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4")
```

I also tried to exclude it from the libraries, using `exclude()` but that didn't worked, it caused more errors. From android studio:

> Dependencies using groupId com.android.support and androidx.* can not be combined but found com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0 and androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0 incompatible dependencies